# FindAllPeersAsync() and StreamSocket.ConnectAsync() issue

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, bluetooth

I am trying to connect to a printer(by MAC address) and print.  I am encountering several issues that I tried to overcome for hours with no success.  I tried several different Methods:

**Method 1:** Using PeerFinder.AlternateIdentities["Bluetooth:SDP"] = "{00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB}" **works on first attempt to connect**. When I try to reopen the connection after closing connection, it was not able to find any paired devices.  When I exit application and rerun, I get the following exception: **"Element not found. (Exception from HRRESULT:0x80070490)** at socket.ConnectAsync()

```
//Search for devices based on service
PeerFinder.AlternateIdentities["Bluetooth:SDP"] = "{00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB}";

//bluetooth device to connect to
var m_bluetoothDevice;

//paired bluetooth device list 
var m_pairedDevices = await PeerFinder.FindAllPeersAsync();

if (m_pairedDevices.Count > 0)
{
    foreach (PeerInformation device in m_pairedDevices)
    {
        //Find the device with matching bluetooth mac address (eg. "00:AA:BB:CC:DD:EE")
        String macAddr = device.HostName.RawName;
        if (macAddr.Contains(m_bluetoothAddress.ToUpper()))
        {
            m_bluetoothDevice = device;
            break;
        }
    }
}

//Device not paired
if (m_bluetoothDevice == null)
    throw new Exception("Device was not paired with system.");

StreamSocket socket = new StreamSocket();
if (socket != null)
{
    //Connect to device. Run this task synchronously
    IAsyncAction taskConnect = socket.ConnectAsync(m_bluetoothDevice.HostName, m_bluetoothDevice.ServiceName);
    taskConnect.AsTask().Wait();
    if (taskConnect.ErrorCode != null)
    {
        throw (taskConnect.ErrorCode);
    }
}
```

**Method 2:** Using PeerFinder.Alternative["Bluetooth:Paired" = "", I am **able to connect once**.  After closing connection and reopening connection, I get the following Exception **"Element not found. (Exception from HRRESULT:0x80070490)** at socket.ConnectAsync().

```
//Search for devices based on service
PeerFinder.AlternateIdentities["Bluetooth:Paired"] = "";

//bluetooth device to connect to
var m_bluetoothDevice;

//paired bluetooth device list 
var m_pairedDevices = await PeerFinder.FindAllPeersAsync();

if (m_pairedDevices.Count > 0)
{
    foreach (PeerInformation device in m_pairedDevices)
    {
        //Find the device with matching bluetooth mac address (eg. "00:AA:BB:CC:DD:EE")
        String macAddr = device.HostName.RawName;
        if (macAddr.Contains(m_bluetoothAddress.ToUpper()))
        {
            m_bluetoothDevice = device;
            break;
        }
    }
}

//Device not paired
if (m_bluetoothDevice == null)
    throw new Exception("Device was not paired with system.");

StreamSocket socket = new StreamSocket();
if (socket != null)
{
    //Connect to device. Run this task synchronously
    IAsyncAction taskConnect = socket.ConnectAsync(m_bluetoothDevice.HostName, "{00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB}");
    taskConnect.AsTask().Wait();
    if (taskConnect.ErrorCode != null)
    {
        throw (taskConnect.ErrorCode);
    }
}
```

Anyone experiencing the same issue?  What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm a bit late to the game but did you find a solution to this?